# Use format [xxxYY] instead of [n] as reference of manual bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I'm using:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{mer04}
  N. Meratnia, A. de By
  \emph{Spatio-temporal compression techniques for moving objects},
  Springer Berlin, Heidelberg,
  2004.
\end{thebibliography}
```

So when printed, the bibliography appear as:

> [1] N. Meratnia, A. de By *Spatio-temporal compression techniques for
>   moving objects*, Springer Berlin, Heidelberg, 2004.

and wherever I get the command `\ref{mer04}`, the reference string `[1]` appears. 
It's perfect, but my professor prefers the notation `[mer04]` instead of `[1]`, and wants the entire bibliography page ordered alphabetically.

How can I do that?

Comment: `\bibitem[Mer04]{mer04}`; you'll have to adjust the argument of the `thebibliography` environment to be right for the widest label.

Comment: Cool, Latex always have the right answer! There's a way to order the biblio by label?

Comment: No, without BibTeX you have to sort your `\bibitem`s by hand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you prepare the bibliography manually, you can add the optional argument:

```
\bibitem[Mer04]{mer04}
  N. Meratnia, A. de By
  \emph{Spatio-temporal compression techniques for moving objects},
  Springer Berlin, Heidelberg,
  2004.
```

Remember to set the argument to the `thebibliography` environment to the widest label, for instance

```
\begin{thebibliography}{Mer04}
```

You decide the sorting order, if you don't use BibTeX.